# Who decides on new employee to be remote or not?

Tags: hiring, company-policy, remote-work

I am the lead of a small team (3-5 people), so the responsibility of hiring new employees of my team is on my own (of course technical and cultural-fit parts of the interview), so the on-boarding. On the way to hiring junior employees, I experienced better when working with other colleagues in the office than when we were working remotely. So I decided to require the presence in the office for at least some days in the week for the applicants.

Me, as someone who is responsible for on-boarding and training junior guys, will have much more trouble when working remotely. But my manager -who is also the CTO and the co-founder of the corporation with much more experience than me- thinks differently. He explains that by allowing remote applicants to apply, we will have much more talents in the end.

So it seems we have a kind of conflict here on this subject.

The main question is that who is the one who should decide on this subject?

Note that:

1. remote applicants will be still of the same country
2. The corp is OK with the presence of future employees
3. The position we are talking about is "Junior Backend Developer" in a logistic company if matters

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace :) please take the [tour] and check the [help/dont-ask] so you can start to better know this Stack. I also posted an answer for your consideration, hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be all one way or the other.  If you're worried about onboarding, remote but with a 1 week or 2 week in office start (travel paid by the company of course) could make everyone happy.  Many big tech companies used to do something like this for employees at smaller offices

Comment: As it happens, I talked to my direct manager about that subject. (Just a normal conversation) I'm in the office one day a week currently. I said "I calculated that a company wanting me to come to the office 5 days a week would have to pay me £10,000 more just so that I have the same money in my pocket. And that's ignoring my travel time". He said "that sounds about right". So it doesn't matter what you decide. What matters is whether you'll find any takers for your job offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The main question is that who is the one who should decide on this subject?

At the end of the day this boils down to company policies and procedures. It also boils down to "what you boss wants".

Yes you can express your point of view, and suggest that being physically there would help because A, B and C reasons. If you express them politely and your point is valid any reasonable boss would agree.

But at the end of the day your boss has the final word. If he has more experience than you, as you say, they surely have good reasons to see things this way.

Perhaps you should give the remote status a chance. See how it goes and if it really represents a lot more effort and work for you then bring this to your boss and discuss how to sort this out.

> On the way to hiring junior employees, I experienced better when working with other colleagues in the office than when we were working remotely

Things like these (with more details, of course) are the reasons you should present to your boss when discussing about this status.